# Get Id from a textview inside a Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My problem is pretty simple but I can't seem to solve it:

I need to get the ID of a textview inside a listview. I need this because I have a treemap of objects, and the way I'm designing my app I need to have an id for each object.. so the id needs to be the same as the id in the listview. Imagine this scenario:

I click in an item in the listview, and that item represents an object that is stored in the treemap. The only way I can know which object was clicked is if I get the id from the clicked item and then search it down in the treemap.

The problem is if I do:

```
_mylistview.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);
```

I get the index of the item (it will be equal to 'pos'), and not a real ID. Say its the 3rd element, it will return 3 (if I delete the 2nd element, the if of the old 3rd will now be 2, so I can't trust this numbers in my implementation).

Is there any simple way to solve this? Can I get the real Id of the item I click or create?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

How are you binding data to the listview exactly?

You should be overriding `onListItemClick` with your logic. This gets passed a `long id` which you can define (in a custom adapter, if need be).

Comment: I'm using an arrayadapter (have an arraylist<string> with the strings I want)

Comment: How are you relating the Strings to the objects in the TreeMap?

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do with the Ids. Each string is present in the listview. If I could get the listview item id, I could save it in each object of the treemap. This way when the item was clicked, I could get its ID and find the respective object in the treemap.                                                                                                                                (PS: the strings are not unique in the listview, thats why I cant use themselves as keys for the treemap)

Comment: The problem you have then, is if you've reordered or deleted rows from the ListView?

Comment: Exactly! I can't use the getItemIdAtPosition because if I delete one of the items, the "ids" that getitemidatposition return change!

Comment: You could override `getItemId` for the adapter to return an ID of your liking; which you'd presumably pass to the adapter in the first place (or could could find some workarounds). OR you could use listAdapter.getView(pos, convertView, parent) to get the view for that row and retrieve the textview for it. I'd recommend the former, though the latter will probably be easier.

Comment: Do I need to extend arrayadapter to use getView or can I use it with the normal ArrayAdapter? I can't seem to understand the arguments of getView (except the position), can you point me in the right direction (I've read the reference manual, but it still doesn't make many sense to me :X)

Comment: You can extend ArrayAdapter, but that would just be pretty minimal. For getView you'd only need to do `super.getView(args)`, because you aren't changing how getView is working.

Comment: Tried _adapter.getView(position, null, null).getId(), but it's giving me always the same ID so I guess its not the item ID but something else..

Comment: Well.. didn't solve the problem as I wanted.. I had to verify if the item I was inserting in the list was unique, and if it wasn't add it an suffix with a number like (1) and (2) and so on.. it's not pretty but it does the job. best regards and thanks for all the help @Estel